# convert from C array (column-major) to armadillo matrix (arma::mat) without copying

Tags: c++, c, armadillo

I have a pointer to a column-major C double array which would like to convert into a `arma::mat` which I understood from the doc is column-major as well.

I have seen the function `std::transform` but I believe the matrices in std are row-major. In the armadillo package there is the `conv_to<mat>::from()` which seems to work with either `std::array` or `arma::mat`, will this work with a column-major C array?.

Could you please tell how to pass the C structure to `arma::mat` without copying and back to a C array?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation of armadillo:
(http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat)

> Advanced constructors
>
> ```
> mat(ptr_aux_mem, n_rows, n_cols, copy_aux_mem = true, strict = false)
> ```
>
> Create a matrix using data from writable auxiliary (external) memory, where ptr_aux_mem is a pointer to the memory. By default the matrix allocates its own memory and copies data from the auxiliary memory (for safety). However, if copy_aux_mem is set to false, the matrix will instead directly use the auxiliary memory (ie. no copying); this is faster, but can be dangerous unless you know what you're doing!
>
> The strict parameter comes into effect only when copy_aux_mem is set to false (ie. the matrix is directly using auxiliary memory)
>
> - when strict is set to false, the matrix will use the auxiliary memory until a size change
> - when strict is set to true, the matrix will be bound to the auxiliary memory for its lifetime; the number of elements in the matrix can't be changed
> - the default setting of strict in versions 6.000+ is false
> - the default setting of strict in versions 5.600 and earlier is true

Comment: many thanks for your answer. Is there a way to return an `arma::mat` back to a column-major C array without copying?

Comment: Probably with ".memptr()" - just look at the documentation. I never used armadillo before...